# Is it a bad idea to use the cluster ID from clustering text data using K-means as feature to your supervised learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, cluster-analysis, supervised-learning, feature-engineering

I am building a model that will predict the lead time of products flowing through a pipeline.

I have a lot of different features, one is a string containing a few words about the purpose of the product (often abbreviations, name of the application it will be a part of and so forth). I have previously not used this field at all when doing feature engineering.

I was thinking that it would be nice to do some type of clustering on this data, and then use the cluster ID as a feature for my model, perhaps the lead time is correlated with the type of info present in that field.

Here was my line of thinking)

1) Cleaning & tokenizing text.

2) TF-IDF

3) Clustering

But after thinking more about it, is it a bad idea? Because the clustering was based on the old data, if new words are introduced in the new data this will not be captured by the clustering algorithm, and the data should perhaps be clustered differently now. Does this mean that I would have to retrain the entire model (k-means model and then the supervised model) whenever I want to predict new data points? Are there any best practices for this?

Are there better ways of finding clusters for text data to use as features in a supervised model?

Comment: Can You give more information about this text feature? what does it contain precisely? are you sure that you can't have all possible values during of this feature in the training set?

Comment: The text feature is a free text field. So it can contain anything really. However, often larger, high level applications/products names. Products range from full scale applications to microservices to 3pp software, so a lot of different words are possible. I can not use all the words as features.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the urge to use an unsupervised clustering algorithm first to see for yourself, which clusters were found. And of course you can try if such a way helps your task.

But as you have labeled data, you can pass the product description without an intermediate clustering. Your supervised algorithm shall then learn for itself if and how this feature helps in your task (of course preprocessing such as removal of stopwords, cleaining,  tokenizing and feature extraction needs to be done).

Depending of your text descriptions, I could also imagine that some simple sequence embeddings could work as feature-extraction. An embedding is a vector of for example 300 dimensions, which describes the words in a manner that `hp  office printer` and `canon ink jet` shall be close to each other but `nice leatherbag` shall be farer away from the other to phrases. For example [fasText-Word-Embeddings](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html) are already trained in english. To get a single embedding for a sequence of `hp office printer`one can take the average-vector of the three vectors (there are more ways to get an embedding for a whole sequence, for example doc2vec).

But in the end you need to run tests to choose your features and methods!

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the good answer. The problem is that my text fields are very product and organization specific. Not many english words at all, but more abbreviations, some internal product codes and more. So I don't think that a pretrained model will help that much here. I could of course train my own Doc2Vec model on my corpus and do some averaging but I am not sure if I have a large enough corpus to do this.